# scala-arm. Return type

Tags: scala, scala-arm

I'm using [scala-arm](http://jsuereth.com/scala-arm/usage.html) library to automatically release/close resources (for example `InputStream`).

But the problem is that code below returns `ExtractableManagedResource[Int]`, not just `Int` as I want.

```
val result = for(responseStream <- managed(response.getResponseBodyAsStream)) yield {
    val localResult: Int = 1
    localResult
}
// result is of type ExtractableManagedResource[Int]
```

Is there any option to return `Int` and overcome wrapping result to `ExtractableManagedResource`?

EDIT: I know that I can just declre `result` variable as `var` and assign to it from inside the `for-comprehension`, but I want more scala-idiomatic way, i.e. without using `var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is easier to implement with the monadic approach by using the aquireAndGet feature

```
managed(response.getResponseBodyAsStream) acquireAndGet { 
responseStream =>
    val localResult: Int = 1
    localResult
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

```
result.opt.get
```

Refer to your own link, under the title "Monadic style", for further details.

Comment: to be a little cleaner you can use the "acquireAndGet" syntax